# Can the union type be the generic parameter?

Tags: typescript

```js
function fun3<T extends string>(arg: T) {
  return arg.length;
}

const aa = fun3<
    | "--text-color"
    | "--background-color"
    | "--border-radius"
    | "--border-width"
    | "--border-style"
    | "--border-color"
  >("--border-color");
```

I assign the fun3 generic

```
| "--text-color"
    | "--background-color"
    | "--border-radius"
    | "--border-width"
    | "--border-style"
    | "--border-color"
```

, but I think this is not the string type, why I can assign it to the function?

Comment: That is *assignable* to the `string` type. The type system would not be nearly as useful if you couldn't assign supertypes to subtypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It's allowed since that union of strings is *assignable* to `string`. See this diagram above. `"a"` is apart of `string`. That means we can give anything that expects a `string`, an `"a"`. However, we cannot give it a `1` because `1` is not in the `string` circle.

You may use `extends` to check assignability, or use an assignment directly (but this tends to be more troublesome):

```
type Check01 = "a" | "b" extends string ? true : false;

const check01: string = null as unknown as "a" | "b";
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXq7JN)

---

Let's pretend that this is not the case for a moment. If there is no generic constraint, then what would you pass?

```
function myFunc<T>(arg: T) {
```

This simple doesn't make sense (why would you only be able to pass `unknown`?) and is not useful at all.

---

[diagram source](https://type-level-typescript.com/02-types-are-just-data)

Comment: const check01: string = null as unknown as "a" | "b";
what is this meaning? why is there a "unknown" keyword?

Comment: Otherwise it'll say that you can't cast `null` to `"a" | "b"`. Of course, you could change `null` to an empty string `""` to remove the need for it, but I just made a generalized example.